# ie11 issues with Nested showModalDialog

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8, nested, internet-explorer-11, showmodaldialog

I am working on a Web Application that uses many modal dialogs to take inputs. The issue started when I started making the app compatible with IE11 (it works perfectly fine in IE8). The Modal Dialog boxes return values perfectly when when called from the main page, but when I create a Modal Dialog from a Modal Dialog, the value is returned but is not caught and is taken as `undefined`.

```js
//calling the values
var ret = ShowDialogOpen(pageUrl, width, height);

function ShowDialogOpen(PageName, strWidth, strHeight) {
    var DialogOptions = "Center=Yes; Scrollbar=No; dialogWidth=" + strWidth + ";          dialogTop=150px; dialogHeight=" + strHeight + "; Help=No; Status=No; Resizable=Yes;";
    var OpenUrl = PageName; 
    var ret = window.showModalDialog(OpenUrl, "Yes", DialogOptions);
      
    return ret;
}

//Dialog returning values
function ReturnValues() {
    var lstBox = document.getElementById("lst_Name");
    var texts = "";
    var values = "";
    for (i=0; i<lstBox.options.length; i++) {
        texts = texts + lstBox.options[i].text + "!";
        values = values + lstBox.options[i].value + "!";
    }

    window.returnValue = texts + "$" + values;
    Close();
    return false;
}
```

This code works perfectly when used via main-page, but when I use it from a Modal Dialog page the `returnValue` is lost.

Comment: Close(); is function

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a bug in a Security patch released by MS recently:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2014/12/09/december-2014-internet-explorer-security-updates-amp-disabling-ssl-3-0-fallback.aspx

Comment: We [released a patch](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/3025390) that resolved this today.